What do I need to do to extend this hearth?
I purchased my first home recently and one of the major items in the home inspection is that the hearth is not up to code. The hearth is made of brick; code requires that the brick (or other non-combustible material) extends 16'' beyond the doors of the hearth. Currently, it's closer to 12''.
Is this something that can realistically be fixed DIY? My expectation is that I need to cut out some carpet, put in some bricks and seal it. But my knowledge of what to do and how to do it ends there. I suspect that this means it's better to pay someone to do this, but figured I'd check here first.
I'm not currently in hot water with the insurance company, but I'd like to start fixing some of the items listed in the home inspection so that the next person doesn't have to. Until the fireplace is up to code I don't dare to actually use it.. and it's nearly winter soon, so it would be nice to get it up to code.


For a small brick job flat on the floor it should be easy to DIY for a first timer.  Just need the bricks and some mortar.  The problem is finding mortar in a small enough package for that job.  Youtube vids and some reading should give enough information.

We don't know what the floor is under the carpet.  Your "cut out carpet and put more bricks down" would work.  It just depends whether you care about the brick pattern—if you want to match the alternating pattern closer to the fireplace you'll need to remove the parallel bricks and fill that space with alternating.  And odds are new bricks won't match, tone-wise, but with use they'll probably get closer.

Code may dictate for new items, but things that existed before the code was codified are often "grandfathered in". Could this fireplace be older than the 16"-requiring code/ Would the glass door oven-style fireplace have some effect on less hearth being required?

It's quite possible this was grandfathered in. The fireplace was put in place in the 90s, and it not being up  to code did show up on the prior home inspection report from the past buyer.
I'm intending to replace the carpet (either myself or with a professional) with alternate flooring eventually, so it seems like it might be wise to wait until I do that and then do it all in one go.

We can't answer whether you can do this or not as we do not know your abilities, nor what tool you may have at your disposal.
That said, adding another row of bricks is fairly simple. Bricks come in a width at or close to 4 inches, so a row laid perpendicular to the front row of existing bricks will get you your 16 inches that you need. You will need to do the shopping to find the bricks that best match what you have.
You will need enough bricks to complete the job, Mortar for placement. A 5 gallon bucket to mix the mortar, and a trowel.( for this small job a putty knife can be used.) A rubber hammer is good,to tap the bricks down to the correct height. ( pros just use the handle of the trowel.) A level or straight edge is needed to be sure the bricks are the same height as the old bricks.
It's pretty much lay down some mortar and place the brick.  The trick is getting the mortar to stick the the sides as well.  Search for videos online. There are plenty that show how to lay bricks.
The most difficult part of this is the carpet.  I would pull the carpet back from the wall past the hearth to install the bricks. Then install new tack strips and cut the carpet to conform around the new hearth.  ( This is where I would hire a carpet professional.) Laying carpet is a learned skill. If you do not know it the results can be very bad.
